# How to open OpenStreetMap iD Editor with a Custom Map Data overlay/boundary pre-loaded?

Tags: editor, openstreetmap

In the OpenStreetMap iD Editor (the main one you get on the website when you login and try to edit), there is a way to overlay a custom boundary, as shown in screenshot below.

[image]

Latest Task Manager is displaying the iD editor in an iframe or so, but earlier versions used to just open it in a new tab, with the custom overlay data still working either through a URL param, or maybe some header attached.

How is this done? I want to overlay a similar boundary over iD editor when a user clicks a button on my website and it opens iD editor in a new tab with the chosen co-ordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass on link to gpx as url params.
https://github.com/openstreetmap/iD/blob/develop/API.md

**Edit by nikhil**: Found that in main openstreetmap site, we have to put the gpx param after a **#** instead of putting as a regular query parameter. So, this works:
https://www.openstreetmap.org/edit#gpx=https%3A//server.nikhilvj.co.in/pmgsy/gpx/1445.gpx

[image: screenshot]

Ref: https://github.com/openstreetmap/openstreetmap-website/issues/3540

Comment: I setup the desired boundaries as gpx files, but it looks like the iD editor is having some problem with it. posted issue at https://github.com/openstreetmap/iD/issues/9093